# How to get a APNS token from an existing FCM Token?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We've been using Firebase Messaging with Android and iOS for over a year. Our React Native app currently sends the FCM token to our server for persistence.

We're are adding Braze to handle emails and push. They support Firebase Messaging for Android apps, however for iOS they will only talk to the APNS directly ( not through firebase as we do now ).

Is there a way for us to retrieve the APNS tokens from our saved FCM tokens?

Moving forward we can retrieve the APNS tokens using the method lined out here ( haven't tested ) [How to convert a FCM token to APNS token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972714/how-to-convert-a-fcm-token-to-apns-token). However that appears to be a client side solution, we want to support push for those users who will not open the app before we need to send a push.

We went through the Firebase Admin Rest API, but it doesn't appear to have an endpoint that will allow us to convert. Although it is our first time going through them so we may have miss interpreted the documentation.